# In a generic method, what exception should I throw when a type parameter is unacceptable?

Tags: c#, .net

When the value of a normal parameter is unacceptable (and the requirements can't be checked completely at compile time), we check at runtime and throw an `ArgumentException` if the check fails.

When the "value" of a type parameter is similarly unacceptable, what kind of exception do we throw? Are there any guidelines on this?

(Note: If I try `ArgumentException`, ReSharper wants to complain - which makes me think there may be another kind of exception that's recommended for this.)

Comment: What is the complaint from Resharper?

Comment: @RobertHarvey "Cannot resolve symbol `T`", where `T` is the type parameter.

Comment: Well, `ArgumentException` generally refers to the formal parameter list, and the name of the offending parameter is the usual argument to ArgumentException's constructor, so Resharper is basically complaining that you're referring to a parameter name that's not one of the declared method parameters (when you throw the exception).  Can you use a Type Constraint instead?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I understand that. In my method, any object is acceptable as an argument (so no problem there), but only specific types are acceptable for the type parameter `T` (specifically, public interfaces - neither of which can be expressed in the constraint). So I'd like to know if there is perhaps another kind of exception that I should be throwing in this case. (Resharper's complaint isn't my main concern - maybe I should remove that note.)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1412598

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Care to make it a (summarized) answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a native exception in the .NET Framework for "Invalid Type Parameter Argument."  Jon Skeet [asked about this on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1412598), and ultimately decided to [write his own](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/source/browse/trunk/UnconstrainedMelody/TypeArgumentException.cs):

```
#region License and Terms
// Unconstrained Melody
// Copyright (c) 2009-2011 Jonathan Skeet. All rights reserved.
// 
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
// 
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
// 
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.
#endregion

using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace UnconstrainedMelody
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Exception thrown to indicate that an inappropriate type argument was used for
    /// a type parameter to a generic type or method.
    /// </summary>
    public class TypeArgumentException : Exception
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new instance of TypeArgumentException with no message.
        /// </summary>
        public TypeArgumentException()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new instance of TypeArgumentException with the given message.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">Message for the exception.</param>
        public TypeArgumentException(string message)
            : base(message)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new instance of TypeArgumentException with the given message and inner exception.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">Message for the exception.</param>
        /// <param name="inner">Inner exception.</param>
        public TypeArgumentException(string message, Exception inner)
            : base(message, inner)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor provided for serialization purposes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="info">Serialization information</param>
        /// <param name="context">Context</param>
        protected TypeArgumentException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```